# In my linux system umount gives error : error writing /etc/mtab.tmp: No space left on device

Tags: linux, mount, unmounting

I am trying to unmount on /root and fails with the following error:

> error writing /etc/mtab.tmp: No space left on device

I am trying to unmount both "log" and "abc"

```
df -h

Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                       105G  168K  105G   1% /dev
tmpfs                          105G     0  105G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                          4.0G  197M  3.9G   5% /tmp
tmpfs                           64G     0   64G   0% /ramdisk   
 //192.0.0.0/LogDir       4.0G  4.0G     0 100% /root/m31/log
//192.0.0.0/lazer        4.0G  4.0G     0 100% /root/xyz/abc
//192.0.0.0/LogDir       4.0G  4.0G     0 100% /root/m31/log
//192.0.0.0/lazer        4.0G  4.0G     0 100% /root/xyz/abc
```

Comment: Have you accidentally filled up your root partition? What does `df -h` output?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Your `df -h` dump doesn't show any partition for `/` ... is it normal ? Do you forgot it ? The message you met is clear: you do not have any free space to write `/etc/mtab.tmp` which is used to update `/etc/mtab` accordingly to the current state of your system. Remove some useless file, and it will be ok.

Comment: **//192.0.0.0/LogDir       4.0G  4.0G     0 100% /root/m31/log** . The IP hidden here is a windows machine. We are mounting  //192.0.0.0/LogDir on a Linux system. The memory showing here is also wrong(that would be my second question), I have around 13 G left. This is a distributed system software.

Comment: does `mount|grep " / "` show anything?

Comment: No , it does not